# MongoDB C# Driver 2.0 and ForEachAsync

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am not very familiar with async in C#, but I am trying to understand it better. I am trying to process a list of documents in Mongo, and I am not sure if I have a race condition or if async is special causing this to be fine. Here is my example.

```
var docs = new Dictionary<string, BsonDocument>();
var result = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("mycollection").Find(new BsonDocument());
result.ForEachAsync((bsonDoc) =>
{
    string name = bsonDoc.GetValue("name").AsString;
    if (!docs.ContainsKey(name))
    {
        docs[name] = bsonDoc;
    }
});
```

It seems like if two documents had the same name, then that if statement could be executed twice for the same name.

I am not sure why there doesn't seem to be a straight forward was to do a synchronous for each with the new mongo driver.

Can someone tell me how I should structure the above code, or why it isn't a race condition if I am wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this:

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/crud/reading/

> Finding all the documents in a collection is done with an empty filter and the method Find. Once we have a cursor (of type IAsyncCursor), we can iterate it like we manually iterate an IEnumerable.

So `Find()` is returning an async cursor, which only ever points to one document at a time. The documentation doesn't say explicitly that `ForEachAsync()` won't move the cursor position till after your lambda finishes, but that's presumably how it works (otherwise, the point of a cursor is defeated since you're loading up more than one record at a time into memory).

Thus, you *should* be safe doing what you are, and shouldn't encounter a race condition.

Comment: If it was sync code, it would only insert one document per name and ignore any documents that had the same name as another document which was inserted. With async code, it seems to me that two documents can make it past the if condition before any documents were inserted into the list.

Comment: I see what you're getting at now. You just want to skip adding the document to the dictionary if there are duplicates?

Comment: Yes. This is just an example to show the condition I am concerned about.

Comment: One solution I have is to just use, ToListAsync().Result and do a foreach loop over that. However, it seems like a hacky way to solve the problem. It feels to me that the result of Find() should be IEnumerable.

Comment: Gotcha. I think you should be fine. See tweaked answer.

Comment: Oh ok, I totally misunderstood what ForEachAsync did. I thought it was like a parallel foreach.

Comment: I think the async part in this case simply allows other code to run while the the foreach loop is iterating through records.